# Fatal: Call to a member function read() on boolean 'xcopy'

Tags: php

I use this code to copy folder to another folder. but after i run i get this error.

Fatal: Call to a member function read() on boolean

code :

```
function xcopy($source, $dest, $permissions = 0755)
{
// Check for symlinks
if (is_link($source)) {
    return symlink(readlink($source), $dest);
}
// Simple copy for a file
if (is_file($source)) {
    return copy($source, $dest);
}
// Make destination directory
if (!is_dir($dest)) {
    mkdir($dest, $permissions);
}
// Loop through the folder
$dir = dir($source);
while (false !== $entry = $dir->read()) {
    // Skip pointers
    if ($entry == '.' || $entry == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    // Deep copy directories
    xcopy("$source/$entry", "$dest/$entry", $permissions);
}
// Clean up
$dir->close();
return true;
}
```

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Thankyou

Comment: Did you debug ? Which function is used read() ?

Comment: `dir` returns false in case of error. SO check it's argument `$source`